# Installed jdk 1.8 but java.library.path is still pointing to 32 bit files

Tags: java, linux, centos, java-8

I have installed jdk 1.8 on my centos server (64 bit os) and it is installed successfully, I can even execute java class file using

```
  java Test  //where Test.class is compiled file
```

but my  java.library.path is still pointing to 32 bit libs? how can I change this path.

I check the  java.library.path  via

```
java -XshowSettings:properties
```

the java.library.path points to

```
java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/i386
    /lib
    /usr/lib
```

what is the issue? how can I make it point to other directories like /usr/lib64 ?

Comment: Did you download the x64 JDK, or the x86 one? What do you get when you type `java -version`?

Comment: [root@testCentos home]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: you are right..that is jdk 32 because it doesn't work with java -d64